# Avoid copying objects when passing records as function parameters in Ada

Tags: pointers, ada

When passing a `in record` to a function or procedure in Ada, it's passed by value.

Should I then pass big records as `access constant` to avoid the copy (as you would do in C++)?

Are Ada compilers usually able to optimize that copy automatically?

Comment: Your first sentence is false.

Comment: Save yourself some headaches and don't worry about premature optimization ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No!  The compiler is free to choose by-copy or by-reference.  See the [Language Reference Manual](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-6-2.html)

No!

You could say so.  The compiler is free to choose what it finds best, and it is my experience that compilers "know" how to generate code better than almost all software developers.

Comment: also, tagged types and limited types (and a few others) are _by-reference types_. And in Ada 2012 you can force by-reference with an _explicitly aliased parameter_

Comment: Generally, C++ developers had problems due to deep copy of containers. Containers have to be copied, because centuries ago in C arguments were locally mutable, and if it's allowed to mutate local copy of int in C, it should be allowed to mutate a local copy of hash map of hash maps, and thus local copy has to be created for non-const arguments. In Ada since the inception arguments are not locally mutable, so this problem is not a hot topic, but a something more like premature optimization like others say.

Comment: Note that Ada subprogram parameters use passing modes IN, OUT, or IN OUT. As said in other responses the compiler determines whether to use pass by reference or by copy. The parameter mode can influence the decision of the compiler. A parameter passed using IN mode is immutable within the called subprogram. A parameter passed using OUT mode must be modified because its value is considered invalid until it is modified. A parameter passed using IN OUT mode is mutable, but has a valid value when it is passed to the subprogram.